# How to input website using os.execute("input text \"...\"")

Tags: string, lua, string-formatting

```
os.execute("input text \"tp://www.lua.org/manual/2/2.1/\"");
os.execute("input text \"tp://www.lua.org/manual/2/3.1/\"");
                                                   4
                                                   5
```

I want to set a variable called `i`,

```
for i =2, 5, 1 do
    os.execute("input text \"tp://www.lua.org/manual/2/**i**.1/"");
```

However, I failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse it inside the string. Like this:

```lua
for i = 2, 5, 1 do
    os.execute( string.format("input text \"tp://www.lua.org/manual/2/%d.1/\"", i) );
```

---

Or even better:

```lua
for i = 2, 5, 1 do
    os.execute( string.format([[input text "tp://www.lua.org/manual/2/%d.1/"]], i) );
```

---

See it at work [here on codepad](http://codepad.org/PCoLQR6b).